# The use of C# extension methods to show intention

Tags: c#, coding-style

Say I have a class, `A`, which holds some state:

```
class A 
{
   // Ctor etc.

   string Foo { get; private set; }
   string Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

This class is used thoughout my codebase to hold application state. Ultimately, this state gets written into an XML file to save it. Naturally, I'll write a method to do just that:

```
class A 
{
    // Ctor, the state, etc.

    public string ToXml()
    {
        // Writer implementation goes here
        return xmlString;
    }
}
```

`ToXml` does not require access to any of `A`'s private/protected instance variables, it only uses uses `A`'s public interface. Since that's the case, I can implement `ToXml` as an extension method:

```
class A
{
    // Ctor, the state, etc.

    public static string ToXml(this A instance)
    {
        // Same deal as above
        return xmlString;
    }
}
```

An extension method can only use the outer interface of the class it is extending. So, ignoring extension methods' main uses (extending a locked class, semantic helpers), what's the SO community's opinion on using an extension method for the sole purpose of communicating that a method only uses the outer interface of a class?

I ask this because I personally use extension methods **alot**--perhaps because I enjoy functional programming--but my coworkers dislike the rationale that I do so because I want to communicate that "this particular method *definitely* only uses the public interface of the class".

**Note**: These extension methods will appear as a substitute for their instance equivalents. Because of that, there will not be any of the usual namespace issues that occur with extension methods. This question focuses entirely on the "communicate intent" aspect.

Comment: Well, since that's not the purpose extension method are meant to be used for, I wouldn't do it, even if there shouldn't be any particular contraindication from a technical point of view. Also it could happen that if the static class where you implement the extension methods is out of your scope, you can't use them, even if the extended class is available (i.e. you don't have a "using" for the extension class' namespace), while if you implement them as "normal" methods you don't have this problem.

Comment: The point of extension methods is to make static method "look like" instance methods, especially when you cannot create an instance method (3rd party class, or backwards compatible interface).  So why use them when you could write an instance method?  Also you end up with are methods that are separate from you class and might require a `using` in order to use, but ultimately doesn't look different from an instance class, and therefor doesn't really meet your intention.

Comment: For the sake of this argument, assume that I'm putting the extension methods within the class's definition. There will not be any of the usual `using` concerns.

Comment: @AdamKewley You cannot put the extension methods inside of the class as extension methods have to be inside of a non-generic, not-nested static class.

Comment: I suppose he means in the same namespace. Anyway I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Extension methods exist to extend classes you don't control. Using them for code you do control seems like an abuse of their intention.

Comment: The crucial difference is that extension method required `public` members, while usually you want to encapsulate some details (making them hidden from users).

Comment: Yeah, assume it is within the same namespace, however that's achieved. Does the fact that they're called "extension methods" outweigh the fact that they have restricted access to the class they're extending, a kind-of reverse encapsulation?

Comment: Ultimately if I call a `ToXml` method on a class I really don't care if the method only uses the public API of the class or some private internals.  Just that it creates the xml.  So really it's a matter of having the methods that directly relate to your class inside of that class or outside of it somewhere else.

Comment: @AdamKewley Actually I think they are just intended to be "an extension" to the class, as the others say, to a class that you can't extend otherwise.

Comment: Well, just put it in class B and you already publish that guarantee.  Extension methods, meh, they tend to be grossly overused.  Where are you going to put FromXml()?

Comment: @juharr I agree - this principle does somewhat violate information hiding a little, but the `const` keyword of C++ does something similar - it indicates to both the compiler and developers that a method definitely does not mutate a class.

Comment: @HansPassant `FromXml` would be a static method on `A`.

Comment: Well, that's obvious but why put heavily related code so far away from each other?  You'll have to keep score of elegance points yourself.  Do listen to your team members, they matter a great deal more than strangers on the Internet.

Comment: @AdamKewley You could have a mutable class and then the extension method isn't guaranteed to not mutate it.  Just to not mutate it via private fields.

Comment: @juharr I'm not implying that extension methods are *the same as* `const`; rather that, like `const`, extension methods communicate access information to the compiler & other developers. In an extension method's case it only communicates that the method uses the public interface of `A`.

Comment: @HansPassant The code will not be "far way". In fact, it will likely be in the same file as `A`.

Comment: I'm fascinated by those saying you shouldn't do this. They are plain wrong, wrong, wrong IMO. Using an extension method is exactly what you should do in this sitaution. Adding a `ToXml` method to class `A` would violate the single responsibility principle. `A` is responsible for holding data. Making it responsible for converting to other data formats gives it two responsibilities. So make it an extension method (in a different class).

Comment: @BradfordDillon, Extension methods were created by Microsoft, and first used in the framework they control to extend classes they control. Ergo, you are incorrect: extension methods most certainly do not exist solely to extend classes you do not control.

Comment: @DavidArno I would argue that the extension methods that Microsoft first introduced, for example Linq, are not extensions of code that they control. Microsoft does not control the code for every instance of `IEnumerable` that has been implemented by people since 3.5.

Comment: @BradfordDillon, actually I'll conceed that. They were indeed created originally for the specific purpose of adding functionality to `IEnumerable`, without breaking all classes that implement that interface. However, they have another use - assisting in maintaining the single responsibility principle, which is how the OP is using it (with the caveat that he's incorrectly wanting to put it in the class itself)

Comment: @DavidArno I'll concede that, before writing this question, I wasn't aware that extension methods could not be placed within a non-static class - my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods are an example of the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).  That is, it's open for extension, but closed for modification.

The major benefit of using Extension methods is that you do not have to recompile the class that is being extended, and thus force dependent code to be recompiled.  Also, by not changing the interface, you don't have to worry about any code depending on it breaking.

If you're serious about SOLID principles, then this is a valid argument.  Most developers don't see what the fuss is about.

Comment: Thank you for the literature reference and reply. I'm unfortunately one of those annoyingly anal developer's that wants to use company time to make such a fuss (rather than, you know, work) ;)

Comment: @juharr - which is an argument to NOT put them in the same assembly.  Although, recompilation isn't really the issue, the changing interface is.  If you can rely on the interface not changing, then even if its recompiled you still get benefit.

Comment: How about in the context of quite small (<200 LOC) classes which likely *will* be in the same assembly, how strongly does the logic of "communicating intent" hold without the no-recompilation-necessary benefits? At the moment, there's a cost to using extension methods in that the C# compiler doesn't support putting extensions within a non-static class, so that has to be considered (I didn't think about that before writing the question)

Answer (score 1):

You have a class, `A`, that has a specific responsibility: holding a set of immutable data. If you now add a new method, `ToXml`, your class no longer has a specific responsibility; it has two loosely related responsibilities: holding data and translating that data into another form.

So to preserve the single responsibility principle, such lossely related functionality should exist in another class, eg `DataTransformationsOnA`. As the method is a pure function (it creates a deterministic output from an input with no side affects, it should be made a static method. Therefore, it follows that it can be made an extension method:

```
static class DataTransformationsOnA
{
    public static string ToXml(this A instance)
    {
        // generate xmlSTring from instance
        return xmlString;
    }

    // other transformation methods can also be placed in this class
}
```